# How to preview WooCommerce endpoint pages

Tags: woocommerce

How can I **preview or view** `WooCommerce` endpoint pages such as the `/order-received/` page without placing an order each time I want to view it?

I know how to edit the contents of `WooCommerce` endpoint pages, but I find it hard to work on the front-end if I can't preview the page.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to place a new order each time you want to preview the endpoint page.

Just place the order once and store the endpoint URL somewhere. You can re-visit the endpoint page as often as you want or even refresh the page after making changes in your code/styling.